# Ajax with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I send the url to a php file in chrome extension, and need get response, but doesn't work.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Get pages source",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Get pages source from a popup",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["http://localhost/"]
}
```

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
var parametros = {
            "url" : url
    };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: parametros,
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function(data) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("error");
    }
});

});
```

file.php - Is in the same folder, in localhost

```
<?php 
$resultado = $_POST['url']; 
echo $resultado;
?>
```

and the popup.html

```
<html style=''>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body style="width:400px;">
<span id="resultado">0</span>
</body>
</html>
```

This code only return a empty array.

Not is posible use Ajax in chrome extension?

**EDIT:**

I charge jquery with a local file, not CDN, and work fine.

Other issue is in my code, I thing that is in jQuery.parseJSON.

Thanks to all ;)

Comment: Is the PHP-file located in the extension folder?

Comment: Yes Magnus, the file route is good.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't run PHP in a chrome extension?

Comment: Is the Chrome extension a webserver? Does it have a way to parse and execute PHP?

Comment: No, chrome extension can't execute php. But is posible with ajax send a request to a externar php file. the php file is in localhost, apache server. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016609/how-to-make-a-post-request-using-ajax-in-a-chrome-extension

Comment: It should work. Try using an <all_urls> permission. see where that gets you.  if you get something that means you formatted your url pattern incorrectly.

Comment: I try <all_urls> permission and: "tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*","file://*/*". Doesn't work :( No ajax alerts displayed, succes or error. And console is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with the URL you're trying to POST to.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: parametros,
    url: 'file.php', // That's a relative URL!
    success: function(data) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Assuming your extension's ID is `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`, then your popup will have the URL `chrome-extension://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/popup.html`, and this will result in a request to `chrome-extension://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/file.php`, not your local server that you said you're using in the comments.

You need to use the full URL:

```
    url: 'http://localhost/file.php'
```

Comment: BTW, don't forget to debug your popup, see [how](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging).