# Pass in PHP variables to a JavaScript file that is connected to HTML with <script src>

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a chrome extension and it uses an HTML `<form>` element. On submit it opens to a new page which would process the input and send a notification using it.
When I use the  element so that the script is in the HTML file, it gives an error saying it violates the content security policy (and yes I have added the 'unsafe-inline' with the 'content-security-policy' line to the manifest for the extension- it still gives the same error).
When I try using `var test = "<?php echo $TEST; ?>` it does not work. Instead, the variable gets directly set to `<?php echo $TEST; ?>`.
This is the HTML with the PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            $title = $_GET["title"];
            $iconURL = $_GET["iconURL"];
            $type = $_GET["type"];
            $msg = $_GET["msg"];
            $TEST = "test"
        ?>
        <title>Notification Tester</title>
        <script src="submitted.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>
            code {
                color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                font-family: consolas;
                size: 20;
                background-color: #ebebeb;
                border: 5px, solid, #ebebeb;
                border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 2.5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Code used: </p> <br>
        <code>
              chrome.notifications.create('NOTIFICATION_ID', {<br>
                  type: <?php echo $_GET["type"]?><br>
                  iconUrl: <?php echo $_GET["iconURL"]?><br>
                  title: <?php echo $_GET["title"]?><br>
                  message: <?php echo $_GET["msg"]?><br>
                  priority: 2<br>
              }
        </code><br>
        <button function="back()">Back</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the JavaScript file:

```
var Title = "<?php echo $Title; ?>"
var iconURL = "<?php echo $iconURL; ?>"
var type = "<?php echo $type; ?>"
var msg = "<?php echo $msg; ?>"
alert(Title)
alert(iconURL)
alert(type)
alert(msg)
/*var elements = document.getElementById("form").elements;*/
if (iconURL == "") {
    iconURL = "icon128.png";
}
if (Title == "") {console.warn("Title not supplied!");}
if (msg == "") {console.warn("Message not supplied!");}
/*console.warn("Type = " + selected + "; iconURL = " + iconURL + "; title = " + Title + "; message = " + msg);*/
chrome.notifications.create('NOTIFICATION_ID', {
    type: type.toString(),              
    iconUrl: iconURL.toString(),
    title: Title.toString(),
    message: msg.toString(),
    priority: 2
});
function back() {
    window.replace(main.html)
}
```

The URL when the HTML with PHP is opened is `chrome-extension://gaknckdfbdfkicppeomjebaamoopolel/submit.html?type=Basic&title=test&iconURL=&msg=test` (obviously, the value of variables could change).

Comment: Neither .js or .html files will cause PHP to be executed. PHP can be executed, on the server, inside a .php file. The response is then delivered back to the browser in the returned response. I'm pretty sure with an extension the HTML is already pre-downloaded into the browser when the extension is installed? Therefore it's not ever anything to do with a server (quite apart from having the wrong extension). What server are you expecting would execute this PHP? I would suggest if you need to fetch data from a server running PHP you would need to use AJAX to do that.

Comment: @ADyson how would I do that?

Comment: Do what? Use AJAX you mean? Have you used it before at all? If not you can find many tutorials online.

Comment: I have never heard of AJAX until now

Comment: Ok. Are you new to web development, perhaps? It's something you normally learn about fairly early on if you're writing web applications. It's a way of sending a request to a server to send/receive data without either submitting a form, refreshing the page, or (as you were trying to do) pre-embed server-side code into the page.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-fetch-api-tutorial-with-js-fetch-post-and-header-examples/

Comment: I'm fairly new to web development.

Comment: Ok well I suggest by starting with a tutorial such as the one I've linked above. You need to understand the basic concepts. Once you get the general idea about AJAX and move on to integrating into your chrome extension, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016609/how-to-make-a-post-request-using-ajax-in-a-chrome-extension might be relevant as well - it's not something I have personal experience of but it looks like you need to do a bit of extra config to allow AJAX requests to be sent from an extension.

Comment: @miken32 that's not applicable when the file in question is a plain HTML file served from a browser extension (not from a server running PHP). Did you read the question and comments fully before nominating that as a duplicate?

Comment: You are correct @ADyson I didn't catch that it was an extension. I've updated the dupe target. Have a pleasant day.

Comment: @littleBitsman you can read the query string variables in the URL directly from Javascript. You'll need to set them in a script block in the main HTML before including the external script file if you want to use them there.

Comment: I found a way to achieve what I was looking for using the answer to this question from @ADyson: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016609/how-to-make-a-post-request-using-ajax-in-a-chrome-extension Thanks for the help.